# How can I trigger intent user free input

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a bot that should collect feedback.

For example:

```
Bot: Leave your feedback

User: Everything is great!
```

My idea was to use a fallback intent for this. But the problem is that the bot has many other intents that can react to this input.

For example, if a user writes the word - email to a user in feedback, another intent is triggered.

How can you implement the preservation of the input in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Create an intent to collect this free form feedback.  You will need to trigger this intent with an event or based on earlier user input with training phrases like "I want to tell you something" or "provide feedback", etc.

Once they are in this intent, you can use a parameter with @sys.any as the entity in a parameter to collect that feedback.

[image: screenshot of the dialogflow intent page showing the actions and parameters section with Parameter named Feedback and the Entity @sys.any and a custom prompt]

Here is what that looks like:

[image: screenshot of the Dialogflow testing pane]

In that example there is a default response configured and you could customize the response or even enable fulfillment to send the input to a Cloud Function or webhook for processing, etc.

Comment: The problem is not in saving but in triggering. I cannot clip based on user input as it can be anything. Also, this input can trigger a different intent. How can I trigger an intent after a free input using an event?

Comment: Take a look at my revised reply answer, it should be more clear.